# Using NDbUnit with tables that have a table schema

Tags: ndbunit

I am having issues using NDbUnit with tables that have their own schema -  ie:

```
CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.MyTable01
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Is this a supported scenario? What do I need to do to get this to work?

(working fine when the table is dbo.MyTable01)

Answer (score 0):

What version of NDbUnit are you using?  Earlier releases failed to support explicit schema prefixes but the more recent releases should properly support them.

Comment: This *is* supported on databases that properly support schemas.  See the SQL Server database that's created in the following script: http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/source/browse/trunk/NDbUnit.Test/Scripts/sqlserver-testdb-create.sql

This properly creates a 'second schema' in the DB called [OtherSchema] which the NDbUnit unit tests then run against just fine.

Note that the VS DataSet designer doesn't properly add schema prefixes to your dataset -- after dropping tables into it you must then add schema prefixes to the tables in the XSD yourself.  After this, NDbUnit DOES support schemas.